# Switching between postdoc fellowships

Tags: funding, career-path, postdocs, denmark

I am non-EU citizen working as postdoc at a university in Denmark. Not so long ago I won two postdoc fellowships, of which I accepted one, and that's where I am currently getting my salary from. I can still accept the other (at least try), but I am struggling to understand whether it is a good idea.

Arguments in favor of accepting:

- my PI tells me it may be possible to use this new fellowship to promote me to Assistant Professor
- new fellowship means a longer period with guaranteed income and residence rights
- the project for which I won that fellowship is more interesting (though also more challenging) than what I am currently working on

Arguments against:

- I don't know if switching to a different fellowship and leaving a research project unfinished won't be a spot on my CV; it's unlikely I will be able to finish the "old" project while working on the "new" one, and also not possible to finish the "old" project before it's time to switch
- I don't know what will happen if my PI's smart plan to promote me fails to work for some reason; it won't be nice if it turns out I cannot be promoted but also can't continue working as a postdoc because I have used up my allowed number of prolongations of my postdoc position

Would be interested in hearing any feedback.